# The distance from a point to a union of sets is the infimum of the distances

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My intuition tells me that the following statement must be true:

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $(E_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of subsets of $X.$ Then, for any $x \in X,$
>    $$ d \left(x, \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \right) = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} d(x, E_n). $$

However, I have only been able to prove one inequality (which is trivial): since $d(x, E) \leq d(x, E_n)$ for every $n,$ $d(x, E) \leq \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} d(x, E_n).$

It would help me a lot if someone could complete the proof or give a counterexample for my statement.

Comment: $E$ denotes, of course, the union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For any $\epsilon>0, \quad\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}}d(x,E_n)< d(x,E)+\epsilon$.**

*Proof:* The distance $d(x,E)$ from a point $x$ to a set $E$ is defined as $\inf_{y\in E}d(x,y)$. Choose a point $y\in E$ such that $d(x,y)<d(x,E)+\epsilon$. Since $y$ must be in at least one of the sets $E_n$, the result follows.

Comment: If such a $y$ did not exist then $\inf_{y\in E}d(x,y)$ would be at least $d(x,E)+\epsilon$, because $d(x,E)+\epsilon$ would be a lower bound for $d(x,y)$. This contradicts the definition of $d(x,E)$.