# Ball around a set equals union of balls around each of its points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have this problem:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A \subseteq X$. Define for any $ \epsilon > 0$:
    $$B_d(A,\epsilon) = \left\{ x \in X \ : \ d(x,A) < \epsilon \right\}.$$
    Show that $B_d(A,\epsilon) = \bigcup_{x \in A} B_d(x,\epsilon)$.

I was trying to show the double inclusion, but I am not sure about anything. I know that $d(x,A)$ is defined as:

$$d(x,A) = \inf \left\{d(x,a) | a \in A\right\}.$$

My attempt went as follows:

\begin{align*}
y \in B_d(A,\epsilon) &\Rightarrow d(y,A) < \epsilon\\
                 & \Rightarrow \inf \left\{d(x,a) | a \in A\right\} < \epsilon\\
& \Rightarrow \exists z \in A (d(y,z) < \epsilon)\\
&\Rightarrow \exists z \in A (y \in B_d(z,\epsilon))\\
&\Rightarrow y \in \cup_{z \in A} B_d(z,\epsilon).
\end{align*}

I doubt this is correct. And I don't know about the other inclusion. Does anybody have a very rigorous proof of this fact?

Comment: I think every step in your proof is 'equivalent', didn't it?

Comment: I am not sure. I don't even know if it is correct. It's probably missing some steps.

Comment: well, I guess you should check step by step.

Comment: Hint: The distance from a point to a union of sets is the infimum of the distances from the point to each of the sets. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240510/the-distance-from-a-point-to-a-union-of-sets-is-the-infimum-of-the-distances/3240544#3240544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling the minor gap in the forward inclusion:

Take $p \in B_d(A,\varepsilon)$. So $d(p,A) < \varepsilon$. Suppose that for *all* $x \in A$ we would have that $\varepsilon \le d(x,p)$.

This means that $\varepsilon$ is an lowerbound for the set $\{d(x,p): x \in A\}$ and $d(p,A)= \inf \{d(x,p): x \in A\}$ is the maximum of the set of lowerbounds and we'd have $d(p,A) \ge \varepsilon$ which is a contradiction.

So for *some* $x \in A$, $d(x,p) < \varepsilon$ or equivalently $p \in B_d(x,\varepsilon)$ for that $x$, and hence

$$B_d(A,\varepsilon)\subseteq \bigcup_{x \in A} B_d(x,\varepsilon)$$

For the reverse, if for some $x \in A$ we have $p \in B_d(x,\varepsilon)$ we know that $d(x,p) < \varepsilon$ and so $d(p,A) \le d(x,p)$ (the infimum of a set is a lowerbound of that set) and so $d(p,A) < \varepsilon$ or $p \in B_d(A,\varepsilon)$ and so

$$B_d(A,\varepsilon)\supseteq \bigcup_{x \in A} B_d(x,\varepsilon)$$

and equality ensues.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. For the converse take $y \in \cup_{x \in A} B_d(x,\epsilon)$. There exists $x \in A$ such that  $y \in B_d(x,\epsilon)$. Hence $d(y,A) \leq d(y,x) <\epsilon$. So $y \in B_d(A,\epsilon)$.